# Can't figure out how to prove Eulerian circuit

Tags: graph-theory

I have a graph that is undirected, connected and every vertex has an even degree and I want to prove that a graph like that has a circuit that goes through all edges and only once.

I searched the internet for proves, however I can't understand any of them, I will really appreciate if someone can explain to me how to prove this.

Comment: Use induction on the number of edges. find a cycle in the graph and remove it